# How to create a function to change variables and refresh Kivy app with the updated variables

Tags: python, kivy

The app I am creating in Python 3 using Kivy is to teach myself the Hungarian language. When the app loads it simply shows a word in Hungarian and the English translation. What I want to do is when I click the only button (on_press) I need a function to be called and to replace the visible Hungarian word and English translation with a new one.

```
# hungarian_tutor.py

""" A program to teach Hungarian translated from English """
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from random import choice
import time
import hungarian_language as hl


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1
        self.phrase = choice(hl.basics)
        self.eng_text = self.phrase[0]
        self.hun_text = self.phrase[1]
        self.hun_audio = self.phrase[2]
        self.add_widget(Label(text="English  >  {}".format(self.eng_text), font_size=50))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hungarian  >  {}".format(self.hun_text), font_size=50))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=hl.alphabet, font_size=20))

        self.btn1 = Button(text="New Phrase", font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        #self.btn1.bind(on_press=)


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Every time I create a function I keep getting an error saying 2 arguments given but only 1 required.

Comment: Why are you passing 2 arguments to a function which requires only 1? Or alternatively, why did you write a function which can take only 1 argument, but it needs to take 2?

Comment: I didn't. It turns out I had to create a @staticmethod. It was the only thing that worked. This was the problem, I didn't create a function that required any arguments and I didn't pass any arguments, this is the reason I was asking for help!

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
```

Then the `self.pressed()` method should look something like:

```
def pressed(self, button_instance):
    print(button_instance, 'pressed')
```